# Convert string to ASCII in DB2

Tags: select, db2

I got the following info stored in a table in db2

```
|id| hash  |encode|
|01|2324424| AµÑÖ |
```

So i want in a `SELECT` statement convert every character of the `"econde"` row in a ASCII character equivalent.

I mean if i got `"AB"` stored i expect to get `"4142"`

How can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "ASCII character equivalent"?  Convert the `Ñ` to `N` or something?  What do you want the output to look like?  Note that this would only be for characters that have Latin equivalents - the moment you have say, Russian or Chinese you're out of luck.  What's the system the database is on (iSeries, LUW, z/OS...).  What's the definition of the table/field?  What about non-printing characters (whitespace and other control characters)?

Comment: So, you're looking to get the hex representation?  That _still_ doesn't tell us what platform you're running on, or the encoding of the column itself (and _yes_, this **MATTERS**).  For latin-based characters, there's probably a built-in utility (or one already written somewhere).  However, characters like `µ`, `Ñ`, and `Ö` aren't represented in (standard) ASCII - what do you want to happen to them?